# Specify .doc file encoding when creating with php?

Tags: php

Currently i try to create some of my database export work more automated and i decided to go with exporting data from MySql database to .doc file in php.

So im doing some database work and store complete html  to a $str variable and then write/make new file:

> $fp = fopen($file, 'w+'); 
>   fwrite($fp,$str);
>   fclose($fp);

The problem here is not creating .doc file, but when i download and view that .doc file it's not in UTF-8 it's in unicode.

Comment: a doc file, why not Excel or even CSV, maybe even json

Comment: because i need doc explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do realize that giving a file a `.doc` extension doesn't make it a Word document?

Anyway, if your `$str` and HTML was encoded in UTF-8, so should be the downloaded file. Otherwise send it with an appropriate

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

It cannot reasonably be "in unicode". You need to explain what that means. It's certainly not autoconverted from UTF-8 to UCS-4 (any of the 4-byte raw unicode representations).

However you could include the UTF-8 BOM to make it certain:

```
fwrite($fp, pack("HHH", 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF));
```

Comment: Yes ofc i know .doc extension does not make it word document. header with utf-8 mark is set at the start of processing file. When i open .doc file in microsoft word i see characters like "ī" as "Ä«".

Comment: @arma - Why not create a real .doc file? Using COM of PHPWord if you want a Woord 2007 .docx file

Comment: @Mark Baker the thing is i don't feel that bringing in another library in my project just to generate 1 table.

Comment: @arma: Sending the wrong MIME type to get the file opened in Word is going to get your file marked as potential exploit by filtering proxies. It's a workaround, and you have not much influence over how Word interprets a HTML page disguised as `.doc` file.  The only other thing you can try to make your horrible workaround work is to embed a `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;CHARSET=UTF-8">` and/or `="content-charset"`, and maybe an XML PI for good measure.

Comment: So in the end i finished up with making template with utf-8 meta and then using it for writing fake .doc. All looks good now.