# Random characters being added to .doc file when downloaded using PHP

Tags: php, ms-word, mime-types

I'm trying to make a .doc file download when a user visits a PHP page. Here is the code I am using:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/msword');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.doc"'));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('/testdocument.doc'));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile('/testdocument.doc');
```

For reference, testdocument.doc is a file stored in the root of the server and can be accessed. It is a .doc file with only the words 'testdocument' written inside.

However when I download the test.doc file the PHP script spits out it tells me that I need to convert the file. If I select 'Text Document', it gives me random characters like this:

```
 –œ ‡°± ·                >   ˛ˇ              
   o           q       ˛ˇˇˇ    d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇÏ•¡ Ä        ø
```

spread out over several pages. If I select 'Word Document', it tells me the format is invalid.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Anything come after the `readfile`. Can you `exit` immediately after? Also, the reasoning for the `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary`?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the encoding.

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

You can read more [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680748/specify-doc-file-encoding-when-creating-with-php)

Comment: I already set the content type in the second line of my code. Setting the charset results in a blank .doc file being downloaded.